# outputstream does not write the data as expected

Tags: java, outputstream, flush

My server looks like this:

```
package marshexample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class marshServer {

private ServerSocket ses;
private Reader br;
private OutputStream os;

public marshServer() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try  {
        ses = new ServerSocket(7824);
        Socket s = ses.accept();
        br = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        char[] request = new char[6];
        int count = br.read(request);

        while (!sb.toString().contains("project")) {

            sb.append(new String(request, 0, count));
            count = br.read(request);
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(sb);

        os = s.getOutputStream();
        os.write("string from server".getBytes());
        os.write("empty line".getBytes());
        os.flush();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(sb);

}}
```

The issue is I have to add the string os.write("empty line".getBytes()); in order to make it work correctly. Without this string the massage is not fully sent to the client. (The same situation is with client). So why flush method does not solve this problem? Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Don't convert strings to bytes to write to the OutputStream: wrap the Stream in a Writer, e.g. an `OutputStreamWriter`, and write the String to the `Writer`.

Comment: Also: don't do all of this in the constructor; put it in a method. Constructors are for constructing the `marshServer` instance, not for doing work.

Comment: the problem is elsewhere - the code, without the "empty line" line, is sending the "string from server" after receiving "project" and an additional packet! (despite it is very hard to really understand what it is (trying) to do)

Comment: To Andry Turner: Using Writer provides the same result, the message is not fully sending.

Comment: To Carlos Heuberger: This server is waiting for the message "string from project" from project and after that the server should send the string "string from server". The client looks very similar so I did not add it.

Comment: Have you found a solution please, i have the same problem